# EF: Is Foreign table of a foreign table included when using include?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Lets say `Table1` references `Table2` while `Table2` references `Table3`.

Query:

```
x.Table1.Include(x=> x.Table2)
  .Where(x=> x.something == 1).Select(x=> new{
     T2Model = x.Table2.Select(y=> new{
          T3Val = y.Table3.val
     })
}).ToList()
```

Will `Include(x=> x.Table2)` ensure that `val` from `Table3` would be loaded without issues?

Comment: No, as long as lazyloading is on, you have to include every single foreign entity, but the var in your select will be loaded correctly

Answer (score 2):

Your query should work if you remove the `Include` call:

```
x.Table1
  .Where(x=> x.something == 1).Select(x=> new{
     T2Model = x.Table2.Select(y=> new{
          T3Val = y.Table3.val
     })
}).ToList();
```

Your projection is what ensures that `val` from `Table3` will be loaded, because your Linq to Entities query is going to be translated to sql later, and due to what you are doing in your `Select`, the Linq provider will deduct it needs to do two inner joins to do that projection.

If you don't project using related properties and you want to load them (having lazy loading disabled), then use the `Include` extension method:

```
x.Table1.Include(x=> x.Table2.Select(e=>e.Table3));
```